# Redefining urlseen and urlfrom when using the APA6 style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, apa-style, apa6

I am using Biblatex with the APA6 style and want to change how the fields `url` and `urldate` are rendered.

Other questions/answers on this site suggest using

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
    urlseen = {Abgerufen am},
    urlfrom = {von},
}
```

However this doesn't have the desired result. It seems like `urlseen` is ignored completely and `urlfrom` is just added somewhere in the result, not replacing the strings I want changed.

Even using `\DeclareFieldFormat{url}` and `\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}` doesn't work.

How do I change the strings for `urldate` and `url` when using the biblatex apa6 style?

Answer (score 1):

After diving into the definitions in the biblatex-apa6 package, it seems that it doesn't use the `urlseen` and `urlfrom` strings and instead defines the custom strings `retrieved` and `under`.

Try using

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
    retrieved = {Abgerufen am},
    from = {von},
}
```

instead.